# Deleting a dinamically generated UI in QT?

Tags: qt

I'm doign a file transfer manager on Dialog the needs to dynamically generate a couple of UI elements. Here is the function that generates it:

```
void TransferData::createGraphicalUI(QDialog *parent, qint32 td_id){
    status = new QLabel(parent);
    filename = new QLabel(parent);
    contact_label = new QLabel(parent);
    accept = new IDPushButton(parent,td_id);
    reject = new IDPushButton(parent,td_id);
    cancel = new IDPushButton(parent,td_id);
    progress = new QProgressBar(parent);
    statlayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    frameLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    frame = new QFrame(parent);

    // Stylying the frame
    frame->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);");

    // Setting the messages.
    QString htmlHeader = "<html><head/><body><p><span style='font-weight:792; color:#0000ff;'>";
    QString htmlEnder = "</span></p></body></html>";
    QString contactMsg = "Transfer ";
    QString filenameMsg = "File name: </span><span>" + getFileToBeSent();
    QString statusMsg = "Status: </span><span>";

    cancel->setText("Cancel");
    cancel->setIcon(QIcon(":/Icons/icons/cancel.png"));
    cancel->setVisible(false);


    if (getIsATransfer()){
        // This is a transfer TO, the file will be uploaded
        contactMsg = contactMsg + "to: </span><span> " + getConctacName();
        statusMsg = statusMsg + "Waiting for file to be accepted.";
        statlayout->addWidget(status);
        statlayout->addWidget(cancel);
        accept->setVisible(false);
        reject->setVisible(false);
    }
    else{
        // This is a transfer FROM, the file will be downlaoded
        contactMsg = contactMsg + "from: </span><span> " + getConctacName();
        statusMsg = statusMsg + "Transfer must be accepted before it begins.";
        accept->setText("Accept");
        accept->setIcon(QIcon(":/Icons/icons/ok.png"));
        reject->setText("Reject");
        reject->setIcon(QIcon(":/Icons/icons/cancel.png"));
        statlayout->addWidget(status);
        statlayout->addWidget(accept);
        statlayout->addWidget(reject);
        statlayout->addWidget(cancel);

    }

    status->setText(htmlHeader + statusMsg + htmlEnder);
    filename->setText(htmlHeader + filenameMsg + htmlEnder);
    contact_label->setText(htmlHeader + contactMsg + htmlEnder);

    // Resettign the progress bar
    progress->setValue(0);

    // Putting it all together.
    frameLayout->addWidget(contact_label);
    frameLayout->addWidget(filename);
    frameLayout->addLayout(statlayout);
    frameLayout->addWidget(progress);
    frame->setLayout(frameLayout);

}
```

This is called from a function that has a list of TransferData objects:

```
qint32 TransferManager::addTransfer(TransferData td){

    // Getting the ID for this tranfer
    qint32 transferID = transfers.size();

    td.createGraphicalUI(this,transferID);

    // Adding it to the UI
    ui->globalTMLayout->addWidget(td.getFrame());

    connect(td.getAcceptButton(),SIGNAL(wasClicked(qint32)),this,SLOT(onTransferAccepted(qint32)));
    connect(td.getRejectButton(),SIGNAL(wasClicked(qint32)),this,SLOT(onTransferRejected(qint32)));
    connect(td.getCancelButton(),SIGNAL(wasClicked(qint32)),this,SLOT(onTransferCanceled(qint32)));

    // Adding the TD
    transfers << td;

    // If a transfer is added this needs to be shown
    this->show();

    return transferID;

}
```

Once the transfer is done I need to delete all the elements of the created UI. I do it like this:

```
void TransferManager::removeTransferData(qint32 which){
    if (which < transfers.size()){

        // Deleting the UI
        transfers[which].removeGraphicalUI();

        // Removing the frame
        QFrame *frame = transfers.at(which).getFrame();
        ui->globalTMLayout->removeWidget(frame);

        // Removing the data itself
        transfers.removeAt(which);
    }
}
```

Where removeGraphicalUI is this function:

```
void TransferData::removeGraphicalUI(){

    frameLayout->removeWidget(progress);
    frameLayout->removeWidget(filename);
    frameLayout->removeWidget(contact_label);
    statlayout->removeWidget(cancel);
    statlayout->removeWidget(status);
    if (!getIsATransfer()){
        statlayout->removeWidget(accept);
        statlayout->removeWidget(reject);
    }
}
```

What happens is that the frame is removed but everythign that was inside the frame remains.  I've checked with a printed message an the code IS enering the removeUI function.

So why does this not work and what Is the proper way to delete dinamically generated UI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I haven't found the answer to my question but I did find the way to do this:

Basically the documentation says that when a QWidget descendant object is deleted, all their childs are deleted.

So what I did is basically used the QFrame as the parent for everything BUT the the layouts.

Then when I wanted to delete said frame I would simply invoke:

```
frame->~QFrame()
```

In the removeGraphicalUI() function and NOTHING more. Also I've commented this:

```
void TransferManager::removeTransferData(qint32 which){
    if (which < transfers.size()){

        // Deleting the UI
        transfers[which].removeGraphicalUI();

        // Removing the frame
        // QFrame *frame = transfers.at(which).getFrame();
        // ui->globalTMLayout->removeWidget(frame);

        // Removing the data itself
        transfers.removeAt(which);
    }
}
```

As removing the frame from the GUI was no longer necessary. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: actually to delete frame you would need `delete frame;`

Comment: This is instead of frame->~QFrame()  or besides this?

Comment: @aarelovich `delete` takes care of destructing the object. C++ isn't Borland Pascal :)